# No database file specified. Missing argument: database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I am running a ruby on rails stack with the following configuration :

```
==> ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

==> rails -v
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
Rails 4.1.0

==> gem -v
1.8.23
```

My config/database.yml looks like this :

```
default: &default
 adapter: sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

development:
 <<: *default
 database: db/development.sqlite3


test:
 <<: *default
 database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
 <<: *default
 database: db/production.sqlite3
```

And I am getting the following error in my browser :

```
No database file specified. Missing argument: database
```

The full trace looks like this :

```
`activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:14:in `sqlite3_connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/usr/share/phusion-passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>`
```

When I run bundle install from the root of my project, the output looks like this :

```
==> bundle install
Using rake 10.3.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.3
Using tzinfo 1.1.0
Using activesupport 4.1.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.0
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.0
Using activemodel 4.1.0
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.9.2
Using jbuilder 2.0.6
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using rails 4.1.0
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.0
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: are you trying to run test cases using database cleaner ?

Comment: No. Just created a basic rails app using rails new app and tried to see it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the default should also contain a database key. This is also considered as a valid database configuraiton.

```
default: &default
 adapter: sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
```

Refer: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/37-dry-your-database-yml

Comment: How do you mean...the default should also contain a database key?

Comment: Add `database: db/default.sqlite3` inside the default hash. Just like you added adapter, pool and timeout. The key's value will automatically be overridden by the corresponding development, test or production database values.

Comment: I tried that. But getting the same error. Ran rake db:migrate also.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case. Did you do `rake db:create`? Are you facing any errors on `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes. rake db:create said that the database already exists and rake db:migrate runs without errors.

Comment: Referring to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4db2e1f78044b7f39119daa9589cc6b8ae48f726/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb, the error is thrown only when the config doesnt have a key called database. Check line 13. Which environment are you trying to load? Development?

Comment: In my apache config, I have RailsEnv development so it should load development right?

Comment: This is a dummy rails app I generated with your config/database.yml. It works fine for me. https://github.com/xyris/testing

Comment: Thanks...I used your code but I'm getting the same error. It's probably a configuration on my server. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. I solved my problem by updating rubygem and then running bundle install --deployment

Answer (score 1):

I wonder would it help if you added a `database:` parameter to your default database? (just guessing)

```
default: &default
 adapter: sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
 database: xxx
```